What's Mars mass compared to Earth since there are many different figures around?
According to,
phys.org

it's mass is just 6.4185 x 10$^{23}$ kg, which is around 15% that of
Earth's

According to,
Universe Today

However, it’s mass is just 6.4185 x 10²³ kg, which is around 10.7%
that of Earth’s.

According to,
Letstalkscience.ca

Though Mars is 15% of Earth’s volume, it is only 11% of Earth’s mass.

What's the real figure of Mars's mass compared to Earth?

Using https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/astro_par.html, ~10.74468%. That Mars GM includes Phobos & Deimos, but that doesn't affect the first 6 digits of the mass ratio.

Mars has a mass that is 10.7% that of Earth (NASA Planetary datasheet).
The numerical value of the mass quoted for Mars in your question appears to be correct.
I don't think there are "many different figures around" and the phys.org article, which quotes the correct masses for both planets in the same paragraph, has clearly just calculated the percentage incorrectly.
